# Internet/pinging really slow on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, internet

I think something happened to my ubuntu machine and now going to websites and/or pinging a website is extremely slow.  I am hardwired to my router so it should be pretty fast.

here are the pinging stats:

```
PING www-real.wa1.b.yahoo.com (69.147.76.15) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from f1.www.vip.re1.yahoo.com (69.147.76.15): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=8.89 ms
64 bytes from f1.www.vip.re1.yahoo.com (69.147.76.15): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=9.67 ms
64 bytes from f1.www.vip.re1.yahoo.com (69.147.76.15): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=8.98 ms
64 bytes from f1.www.vip.re1.yahoo.com (69.147.76.15): icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=9.85 ms
64 bytes from f1.www.vip.re1.yahoo.com (69.147.76.15): icmp_seq=5 ttl=55 time=9.67 ms
```

here is info from my ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:d1:90:e5:d9  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::219:d1ff:fe90:e5d9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:51515 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:38137 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:52123136 (52.1 MB)  TX bytes:3774520 (3.7 MB)
          Memory:dffe0000-e0000000
```

Is there I can do or check to find out why it is so slow??

Answer (score 3):

A ping of <10ms to a remote website is **very** good in my books!

Ping your router and see if you get a return of 1-5ms on the first then ~1 on anything after.

However, again, in my books, you have a very good speed!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you aren't misreading? I see that you ping is sub 10 milliseconds which is great!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, 8 ms to get a reply from a site like yahoo, doesn't strike me as particularly slow.  The same ping (I'm at this moment 3 rooms away from my wireless router takes about 27 ms - 1/3 as fast.  But if you think you have a problem, try [traceroute](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man8/traceroute-nanog.genuine.8.html).  It will tell you all the machines your packets pass though and where the bottlenecks are.

Install with `sudo apt-get install traceroute` and run as:

```
traceroute www-real.wa1.b.yahoo.com
```

From my machine, which I consider typical, if not lightning quick or anything:

```
traceroute to www-real.wa1.b.yahoo.com (209.131.36.158), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1)  6.019 ms  6.204 ms  6.499 ms
 2  bras8-l0.sndgca.sbcglobal.net (151.164.184.155)  27.740 ms  28.296 ms  28.719 ms
 3  dist1-vlan50.sndg02.pbi.net (63.200.206.130)  29.193 ms  30.490 ms  32.398 ms
 4  151.164.94.2 (151.164.94.2)  34.704 ms  37.106 ms  39.317 ms
 5  ex1-p3-0.eqsjca.sbcglobal.net (70.245.63.230)  57.745 ms  60.350 ms  62.142 ms
 6  asn10310-yahoo-10g.eqsjca.sbcglobal.net (151.164.248.58)  65.099 ms  25.918 ms  67.205 ms
 7  ae0-p161.msr1.sp1.yahoo.com (216.115.107.59)  67.717 ms ae1-p171.msr2.sp1.yahoo.com (216.115.107.87)  68.103 ms ae0-p161.msr1.sp1.yahoo.com (216.115.107.59)  68.572 ms
 8  te-8-1.bas-a1.sp1.yahoo.com (209.131.32.17)  68.973 ms  69.387 ms te-8-1.bas-a2.sp1.yahoo.com (209.131.32.19)  70.052 ms
 9  * * *
```